# Omnipay Exception not being caught

Tags: exception, try-catch, omnipay

Using Craft CMS implementing Omnipay. Relatively new to Craft and Onmipay but hoping my general concept knowledge is not off here:

This seemed pretty straightforward, an exception should be caught with a try/catch block no?

```
// Validate on Omnipay Credentials
    $formInputData = array(
        'number'            => $info->CardNumber,
        'expiryMonth'       => $info->ExpireMonth,
        'expiryYear'        => $info->ExpireYear,
        'cvv'               => $info->SecurityCode,
        'first_name'        => $info->Cardholder,
        'billingAddress1'   => $info->CardAddress,
        'billingCity'       => $info->CardCity,
        'billingState'      => $info->CardState,
        'billingPostcode'   => $info->CardZip,
    );
    //try/catch for Omnipay Invalid Card Exception
    try{
        $card = new CreditCard($formInputData);
        $card->validate();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'blah';
    }
```

This does NOT catch the exception and instead I'm redirected to an exception page saying the following:
`Omnipay\Common\Exception\InvalidCreditCardException`

`Card number should have 12 to 19 digits`

This is then followed by a stack trace into the CreditCard class where it throws an exception based on any intentional credit card errors I make.

Why is it not catching the exception and performing my catch block? What needs to be done with Omnipay/Craft to get this exception caught so I can redirect the user to the proper page with the errors listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
```

To this:

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to look up why that worked as opposed to without. Thanks again!